# recommender system for hotel prices and promotions

Tags: multiple-regression, data-mining, recommender-system

We are trying to build a web page that will list the rooms (and promotional packages) of a hotel, along with automatically produced prices/rates.

Top 2 in the list has special importance. These two must be a) attractive to the customers b) profitable for hotel owners.

The system has more than one hotels, but this page will list rooms and packages of a single hotel.

The history of the customers will be used if available, e.g. the rooms and promotions they bought before.

Rates and promotion packages differ like:

- A room can be two different prices depending on refundable - nonrefundable payment.
- Include breakfast or not...
- We may consider the availability of room types.
- We may consider customer location. E.g. customers from different countries behave different.
- Season...
- ...

Each hotel may have their own promotion approaches.

At first we considered the "content based recommendation system" approach similar to what described in Chapter 9 of the Mining Massive Datasets book (http://www.mmds.org/ ). However, we noticed that we are not recommending actual rooms, but the promotions. A hotel may have 17 rooms at most so far in our database. But if we consider all promotions, we may have around 25.000.000 choices for a single hotel to chose from. Using the standard content-item based recommendations seems an over kill to me: E.g. create 25M promotions, than cluster/group them, then see the distance of customer profile to promotions... It may take too much time.

Can you suggest some methods/algorithms which may work in this kind of situation? Also include some implementation hints if possible.

Thanks.